# Javafx-FXMLLoader's load method can't create instance of Controller class

Tags: java

I've checked all the solution similar to my problem, but mine still remained the same. My Painter.fxml file, PainterController.java file and Painter.java file that contained main method are all in the same folder, but yet is still giving me run time error. The main problem is that, main class that contained FXMLLoader's load method cannot implicitly create the instance of the controller class during program execution. Please how do I go about this problem?

```
                        MAIN CLASS:
 import javafx.application.Application;
 import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
 import javafx.scene.Parent;
 import javafx.scene.Scene;
 import javafx.stage.Stage;

 public class Painter extends Application
 {
     public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Parent root =FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Painter.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setTitle("Painter");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       launch(args);
    }
 }

                       CONTROLLER CLASS:
// PainterController.java
// Controller for the Painter app
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;

public class PainterController
{
   // enum representing pen sizes
   private enum PenSize{
     SMALL(2),
     MEDIUM(4),
     LARGE(6);

     private final int radius;

     PenSize(int radius) {this.radius = radius;}

     public int getRadius() {return radius;}
    };

    // instance variables that refer to GUI components
    @FXML private RadioButton blackRadioButton;
    @FXML private RadioButton redRadioButton;
    @FXML private RadioButton greenRadioButton;
    @FXML private RadioButton blueRadioButton;
    @FXML private RadioButton smallRadioButton;
    @FXML private RadioButton mediumRadioButton;
    @FXML private RadioButton largeRadioButton;
    @FXML private ToggleGroup colorToggleGroup;
    @FXML private ToggleGroup sizeToggleGroup;
    @FXML private Pane drawingAreaPane;

  // instance variables for managing Painter state
  private PenSize radius = PenSize.MEDIUM; // radius of circle
  private Paint brushColor = Color.BLACK; // drwing color

  // set user data for the RadioButtons
  @FXML
  public void initialize()
  {
    // user data on a control can be any Object
    blackRadioButton.setUserData(Color.BLACK);
    redRadioButton.setUserData(Color.RED);
    greenRadioButton.setUserData(Color.GREEN);
    blueRadioButton.setUserData(Color.BLUE);
    smallRadioButton.setUserData(PenSize.SMALL);
    mediumRadioButton.setUserData(PenSize.MEDIUM);
    largeRadioButton.setUserData(PenSize.LARGE);
  }

  // handles drawingArea's onMouseDragged MouseEvent
  @FXML
  private void drawingAreaMouseDragged(MouseEvent event)
  {
    Circle newCircle = new Circle(event.getX(), event.getY(), 
     radius.getRadius(), brushColor);
    drawingAreaPane.getChildren().add(newCircle);
  }

  // handles color RadioButton's ActionEvents
  @FXML
  private void colorRadioButtonSelected(ActionEvent event)
  {
    // user data for each color RadioButton is the corresponding Color
    brushColor = 
     (Color) colorToggleGroup.getSelectedToggle().getUserData();
  }

  // handles size RadioButton's ActionEvents
  @FXML
  private void sizeRadioButtonSelected(ActionEvent event)
  {
    // user data for each size RadioButton is the corresponding PenSize
    radius = 
     (PenSize) sizeToggleGroup.getSelectedToggle().getUserData();
  }

  // handles Undo Button's ActionEvents
  @FXML
  private void undoButtonPressed(ActionEvent event)
  {
    int count = drawingAreaPane.getChildren().size();

    // if there are any shapes remove the last one added
    if (count > 0)
    {
     drawingAreaPane.getChildren().remove(count - 1);
    }
  }

  // handles Clear Button's ActionEvents
  @FXML
  private void clearButtonPressed(ActionEvent event)
  {
    drawingAreaPane.getChildren().clear(); // clear the canvas
  }
```

}

```
                    RUN TIME ERRORS:

C:\JAVAFX2>java Painter
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at     com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at     com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at     com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$159(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:
/C:/JAVAFX2/Painter.fxml:12

```
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:922)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at Painter.start(Painter.java:12)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$166(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$179(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$177(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$178(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$152(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PainterController
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:920)
    ... 22 more
Exception running application Painter
```

Comment: File `Painter.fxml` needs to be in the same folder as file `Painter.class`  Note I am talking about the compiled class, not the source code file.

Comment: I got you right. All the files are in the same folder; both Painter.fxml and Painter.class are all in the same folder. The issue is this, if I explicitly create the instance of PainterController.java in main class, the program work perfectly as I want. But according to the book (Deitel & Deitel 11 Edition) am using, the FXMLLoader's load method is responsible to load Painter.fxml file and create the instance of PainterController.java at run time.